# Array of arrays initialized as const float* instead of const float **

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I came across this code

```
float range[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* histRange = { range };
```

For me, `{ range }` means 'array of arrays' since the variable `range` is an array of float. Therefore, for me, it would make more sense.

```
const float** histRange = { range };
```

But the compiler (VC++ from VS2019) doesn't like it (expects a const float*)

Could someone explain to me why `{range}` is not an 'array of arrays' (float**), but instead just a regular float pointer?

Interesting fact: When I do

```
float range[] = { 0, 256 };
auto aa = { range };
auto bb = range;
std::cout << typeid(aa).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(bb).name() << std::endl;
```

the output is (in VC++ VS2019)

```
std::initializer_list<float * __ptr64>
float * __ptr64
```

Comment: This doesn't work either: `float* range = { 0, 256 };`  and this will: `const float* histRange[] = { range };`  This is because `{ 0, 256 }` and `{ range }` are not arrays that you can point to, they are lists of values ready to initialize arrays.  Pedantically, `std::initializer_list<T>` doesn't decay to a `T*` the same way that a real `T[]` does.

Comment: @BenVoigt That looks like an answer.

Comment: @cigien: I would expect a proper answer to cover how list-initialization can also be used to initialize a scalar by supplying the arguments expected by its constructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that would make the answer better for sure. If you don't feel the comment is sufficient as an answer, that's reasonable.

Comment: @BenVoigt pedantically a braced list is not a `std::initializer_list` except in certain contexts, which this is not one of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text enclosed by braces is not an expression, and doesn't have a type. A braced list is only allowed in certain contexts, and in each case the language definition specifies the semantics of the larger context featuring that braced list.

In the line:

```
const float* histRange = { range };
```

we are initializing a scalar, not an array. The `[]` syntax is required to declare an array. It is not defining an unnamed array and having `histRange` point to the first element of that array.

The meaning of a braced list as initializer for a scalar (other than `auto`) is that the list must contain 0 or 1 elements; and if it contains 1 element then the behaviour is the same as if the braces were omitted.

Or in other words, initializers for scalars can optionally have braces, e.g. `int x = { 5 };`. This rule has been around since C.

A braced list with more than one element would not be allowed in this context (although gcc accepts it with a warning by default, and ignores any list elements besides the first).

So, `const float* histRange = range;` is allowed because `range` is an array, and there is an implicit conversion from array to pointer-to-first-element-of-that-array, which has type `float *`, and there is also implicit conversion from `float *` to `const float *`.

---

`const float** histRange = range;` would be an error (with or without optional braces) because there is no conversion from `float *` to `const float **`.

---

Also allowed would be `const float *histArr[1] = { range };` which is an array of pointers to const float and length `1`; here you could have a braced list and a longer length.

---

In `auto aa = { range };` , the use of `auto` has its own rules of type deduction, and the rule is that this syntax (without `*` or `[]` in the declarator) deduces `aa` as having type `std::initializer_list<T>` of one element.

Note that it would still not be correct to say that `{ range }` has a type.  The `std::initializer_list<T>` is initialized by the elements of the braced list.

This rule is slightly controversial; in C++11 `auto aa{range};` was the same, but in C++17 it was changed to deduce `aa` to have the same type as `range`.

Comment: thanks, this is a very clear explanation.